# form validation ''required' is not working

Tags: html, reactjs, react-hooks

I have use **Required** corm validation in my input fields and i dont want to submit my form with empty fields. My **required** form validation is not working.

```
function AddCar() {
   const [chasis, setChasis] = useState("");    
   const [model, setModel] = useState("");      
   const [engine, setEngine] = useState("");          
    
   const addCar = (e) => {
         e.preventDefault();
         console.log("submint");
   };
    
   return (
        <div className="addCar">
          <h1>Add Car Record</h1>      
          
          <div className="addCar__form">
            <form>
              {/* Date */}
              <div>
                <label>Chasis No</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  value={chasis}
                  onChange={(e) => setChasis(e.target.value)}
                  required
                />
              </div>
              <div>
                {" "}
                <label>Model No</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  value={model}
                  onChange={(e) => setModel(e.target.value)}
                  required
                />
              </div>
              <div>
                <label>Engine No</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  value={engine}
                  onChange={(e) => setEngine(e.target.value)}
                  required
                />
              </div>
    
              <button type="submit" onClick={addCar} className="btn btn-primary">
                ADD CAR
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default AddCar;
```

I dont want my form submitted by empty fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use onSubmit instead of onClick

```
<form onSubmit={addCar} >

 ....
<button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
    ADD CAR
</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the attribute "value" on your button, i.e value="submit"

```
 <button type="submit" value="submit" onClick={addCar} className="btn btn-primary">
  ADD CAR
 </button>
```

Comment: What is the Role of Value in button?